# comparing t_data and rx_data for errors and giving the error value by total_error "verilog"

Tags: verilog

I have made a bit error rate (ber) file in verilog. In ber module, I have made total_error which compares the t_data and rx_data and totals up the number of errors it gets from comparing.

Here is the code

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module ber
(
  clk,
  rstn,
  T_Data,
  RX_Data,
  total_error,
  enable
);

//inputs
input clk;
input rstn;
input [15 : 0] T_Data;
input [15 : 0] RX_Data;
input enable;
//outputs
output [15:0] total_error;

reg [4:0] i;
reg [15:0] subtotal, next_subtotal;

assign total_error = subtotal;

always @(posedge clk) begin : comb
    next_subtotal = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1)
    begin
      if (T_Data[i] != RX_Data[i] ) 
      begin
        next_subtotal = next_subtotal + 1;
      end
    end
end

always @(posedge clk) begin : dff
  if (rstn==1'b0)
  begin
    subtotal <= 7'b0000000;
  end else
  begin
    subtotal <= next_subtotal;
  end
end
endmodule
```

After making the BER file, I made another file known as BER_STATE_MACHINE where I made a state machine for TRANFERRING AND RECEIVING SIGNALS, I instantiated the ber file with this ber_state_machine file.

Here is the code

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module  ber_state_machine
(
    clk,
    resetn,
    T_Data [15:0],
    T_Valid,
    T_Ready,
    RX_Data [15:0],
    RX_Active,
    RX_Valid,
    total_error  
);
//-----------------------------------
input     resetn, clk;

// DECLARING INPUTS AND OUTPUTS FOR TRASMIT SIGNALS
input [15 : 0] T_Data;      
input T_Valid;
output T_Ready; 

// DECLARING INPUTS AND OUTPUTS FOR RECEIVING SIGNALS
input [15 : 0] RX_Data;
input RX_Active;
input RX_Valid;

//-----------------------------------
output [15 : 0] total_error;
//-----------------------------------

reg [6:0] sel;
reg execute_in;
reg T_Ready;

//------------------------------------------    
ber uut
(
  .clk(clk),
  .rstn(resetn),
  .T_Data(T_Data),
  .RX_Data(RX_Data),
  .total_error(total_error),
  .enable(execute_in)
);
//------------------------------------------        

// MAKING STATE MACHINE HERE //INPUTS
always @ (posedge clk or negedge resetn) // state machine for changing states
begin
    if (resetn == 1'b1) // idle state
    begin
        sel <= 7'b000; // state 0
    end
    else if (T_Valid == 7'b1)
    begin
        sel <= 7'b001; // state 1
    end
    else if (sel == 7'b001)
    begin
        sel <= 7'b010; // state 2
    end
    else if (RX_Active == 7'b1)
    begin
        sel <= 7'b011; // state 3
    end
    else if (T_Valid == 7'b1 && RX_Valid == 7'b1)
    begin
        sel <= 7'b100; // state 4
    end
    else if (sel == 7'b100)
    begin
        sel <= 7'b101; // state 5
    end
    else if (T_Valid == 2'b0 && RX_Valid == 2'b0)
    begin
        sel <= 7'b100; // going back to state 4
    end
end

// STATE MACHINE //OUTPUTS
always @ (posedge clk) // outputs for every state in state diagram
begin
    case(sel)
        7'b000 :
            execute_in = 2'b0; // state 0
        7'b001 :
            T_Ready =    2'b1; // state 1
        7'b010 :
            T_Ready =    2'b0; // state 2
        7'b011 :
            execute_in = 2'b1; // state 3
        7'b100 :
            T_Ready =    2'b1; // state 4
        7'b101 :
            T_Ready =    2'b0; // state 5
    endcase
end  
endmodule
```

After this, I made a test bech to see the behavioral simulation. 
There are few problems that I am getting which I am not able to fix due to less verilog experience.

1. the t_data and rx_data are undefined in the simulation, after the last bit, I can see the value each contains but from 0 - 15, they are undefined. I really dont know whats the problem.
2. I dont see any value in total_error, even though I put errors in t_data and rx_data but I dont see the number of errors in total_error. But I can observe in the simulation that there are errors in t_data and rx_data in their final values.

Here is the code for test bench

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module test_bench();

//inputs
reg execute_in;
reg clk; 
reg resetn;

//inputs for transferring signals
reg [15:0] T_Data;
reg T_Valid;

//inputs for receiving signals
reg [15:0] RX_Data;
reg RX_Active;
reg RX_Valid;

//outputs
wire [15:0] total_error;
wire T_Ready;

//instantiate the unit under test (UUT)
ber_state_machine uut_ber
(
.clk(clk),
.resetn(resetn),
.T_Data(T_Data),
.T_Valid(T_Valid),
.T_Ready(T_Ready),
.RX_Data(RX_Data),
.RX_Active(RX_Active),
.RX_Valid(RX_Valid),
.total_error(total_error)
);

initial begin
            clk = 1'b0;
            resetn = 1'b1;
            repeat(4) #10 clk = ~clk;
            resetn = 1'b0;
            forever #10 clk = ~clk;
end        

initial begin           
            #100
            execute_in = 0;
            #100
            execute_in = 1;

            #100
            T_Valid = 1'b0;
            RX_Active = 1'b0;
            #100
            RX_Valid = 1'b0;
            //************//
            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[0] = 1'b0; // data 0 // make it 0 for error
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[0] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;
            //************//
            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[1] = 1'b1; // data 1
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[1] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[2] = 1'b1; // data 2
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[2] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;  

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[3] = 1'b0; // data 3
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[3] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;                    

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[4] = 1'b1; // data 4
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[4] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[5] = 1'b1; // data 5
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[5] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;            

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[6] = 1'b1; // data 6
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[6] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[7] = 1'b1; // data 7
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[7] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;    

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[8] = 1'b1; // data 8
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[8] = 1'b0; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;     

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[9] = 1'b1; // data 9
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[9] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;       

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[10] = 1'b1; // data 10
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[10] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;      

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[11] = 1'b1; // data 11
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[11] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;     

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[12] = 1'b1; // data 12
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[12] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;     

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[13] = 1'b1; // data 13
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[13] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;      

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[14] = 1'b1; // data 14
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[14] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;    

            #100
            RX_Active = 1'b1;
            T_Valid = 1'b1;
            T_Data[15] = 1'b1; // data 15
            RX_Valid = 1'b1;
            RX_Data[15] = 1'b1; // make it 0 for error
            #50
            T_Valid = 1'b0;     
        end                                                                         
endmodule
```

Please help me out in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic uses an active-low reset.  However, your testbench starts with the reset signal de-asserted (resetn=1), then asserts it (resetn=0) after 40ns.  I think you need to invert the polarity in the testbench:

```
initial begin
            clk = 1'b0;
            resetn = 0; // Assert active-low reset
            repeat(4) #10 clk = ~clk;
            resetn = ~resetn; // De-assert reset
            forever #10 clk = ~clk;
end
```